# Connect two drop downs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdown in the same page. If I select some data from the first filter I get the filtered value. Now If I select some data from the second dropdown the first drop down value will go away.

For example my first drop down has these values

```
 <select class="form-control"id="oneFilter">
                                <option value="" style="display:none;">Department</option>
                                <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                                <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
                                <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
                                <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>

                            </select>
```

My second drop down has

```
<select class="form-control"id="twoFilter">
                                <option value="" style="display:none;">Grades</option>
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                                <option value="D">D</option>

                            </select>
```

**What is happening**
When I select the department it displays all the data related to the department. Now If I select the second filter for grade B then it displays all the data related grade B only. So It's not showing the previous filter.

What I need here is:

1. If I select the department mechanical it should display all the data related to the department.
2. If I select Grade then it should display all the data related to the grades also.
3. And I need one more feature to be added if I want to see in the mechanical department how many of them are in Grade B but that is not working .

Point 1 and 2 are working. Point 3 is not working.

My script is

```
<script>
    $("#oneFilter").on('change', function () {
        var dropdownvalue = document.getElementById("oneFilter")
        var selectOne = dropdownvalue.options[dropdownvalue.selectedIndex].value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/filter1/filter',
            data: {
                'selectedone': selectOne
            },
            success: function (result) {
                
            }
        })
       

    })
</script>
<script>
    $("#twoFilter").on('change', function () {
        var dropdownvalue = document.getElementById("twoFilter")
        var selectTwo = dropdownvalue.options[dropdownvalue.selectedIndex].value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/filter2/filter',
            data: {
                'selectedtwo': selectTwo
            },
            success: function (result) {
                
            }
        })
        
    })
</script>
```

How should I connect these two dropdowns?

I am adding my entire HTML page

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--JS files-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container col-md-offset-1 list">
    <h2 class="grey_text text-center">Students List</h2>

    <div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
        <table id="table" style="table-layout: width: 800%" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Student Email</th>
                    <th>Department
                        <select class="form-control"id="oneFilter">
                            <option value="" style="display:none;">Department</option>
                            <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
                            <option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
                            <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
                            <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>

                        </select>
    </div>
    </select>

    </th>
    <th>Status
        <select class="form-control"id="twoFilter">
            <option value="" style="display:none;">Grades</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>

    </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for each_student in result %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ each_student.student_id }}</td>

            <td >{{ each_student.student_email }}</td>
            <td>{{ each_student.student_department }}</td>
            <td >{{ each_student.student_grade }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#oneFilter").on('change', function () {
        var dropdownvalue = document.getElementById("oneFilter")
        var selectOne = dropdownvalue.options[dropdownvalue.selectedIndex].value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/filter1/filter',
            data: {
                'selectedone': selectOne
            },
            success: function (result) {

            }
        })
        $(".list").empty();

    })
</script>
<script>
    $("#twoFilter").on('change', function () {
        var dropdownvalue = document.getElementById("twoFilter")
        var selectTwo = dropdownvalue.options[dropdownvalue.selectedIndex].value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/filter2/filter',
            data: {
                'selectedtwo': selectTwo
            },
            success: function (result) {

            }
        })
        $(".list").empty();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: First, what does it mean to ***display*** the data like you said above. Second, where is the code you tried to achieve ***point 3***?.

Comment: When I do the filteration data will be fetched from the database and it gets displayed. I couldnt write the script for point 3

Comment: You need to show your `result`s that are returned from server.  Point 2 by using word "also" suggest that it filters data based on filter 1 but to me right now it seems its totally unrelated and just pulls all "B grades" independently from department.

Comment: What is the relationship between departments and grades? Do you want to do the extra filtering in the UI? Is there a third API that filters on both? Does the second API filter on both already? Can you elaborate on that in the question? It's still not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @sonic Yes when I select the grade B it totally pulls independently from the department. What I need is both drop down should work independently.If sometimes if need to filter both the data it should work in that way also. for example if i select computer it should display name,email,department grades of computer department.If I select grade b then it displays name,email,all department of grade b studnets. If I want to filter computer department who are all scored grade A how should I filter it ? this is my question

Answer (score 0):

I think there is multiple way of doing that. It depends on your UI.

For example you can combine those 2 selects using checkbox. When checkbox is `checked` than you should call another method in your backend instead one of those 2. Its easier to prepare it on backend. Of course if backend is in your hands you can prepare another method.

If you are only on front-end then you can see that you have common `department` field and `grade`. So either way... Filtering results from department by filter "GRADES", hiding those rows that has not value specified in filter. You can use `data` attribute on your `tr` and just traversing through them and checking. You can also go the other way around the same thing but checking if any tr consist of your department name if there are multiple departments attached to user, for example `data-department='computer, electronic`. You can develop those 2 methods and apply them independently to those 2 selects. But yeah you see... its seems to much maybe... Therefore it depends from your UI solution...

Comment: can you give with example so that I can understand better.